# Initialize MobileAds in Processing

Tags: java, android, admob, processing

I am using the Java environment "Processing" to code an app. When i try to initialize MobileAds using this code (example):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;


void setup(){
background(0);
}

void draw(){
background(0);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MobileAds.initialize(getContext(), "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
}
```

I get this Error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zziq...`

I already tried the

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MultiDex.install(getContext())
    MobileAds.initialize(getContext(), "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
}
```

approach without success. Any advice would be appreciated.